# Google Guice: How to inject a Scala case class which has Boolean field in its constructor

Tags: scala, guice

I have the following issue:

I need injection for constructor a Scala case class that has fields to store different configs

This class has a Boolean attributes:

```
case class ConfirmConfig @Inject()(  
acceptAlternativeProviders: Seq[String],
acceptManualAlternativeProvidersDisabled: Seq[String],
acceptMoveAlternativeProvidersPerProduct: Map[String, Seq[String]],
skipValidateFlownSegmentsGolMailbox: Boolean)
```

I am injecting this class in a service class (which has business logic) as follows:

```
@Singleton
class GenerateReissueMaskOperation @Inject()(
revalidationService: RevalidationService,
reservationService: ReservationService,
confirmConfig: ConfirmConfig)
```

When I run the app I am getting this error:

> No implementation for java.lang.Boolean (with no qualifier annotation) was bound, and could not find an injectable constructor. Injectable classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
> at java.lang.Boolean.class(Boolean.java:43)

What is necessary to @Inject() a class which has a Boolean Scala case class argument in its constructor?

Thank you very much to anyone who can give me a hand

I am reading the official documentation (https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/) but I don't be able to resolve the problem.

Comment: `@Inject` in Guice require that all constructor params have some implementation defined that `Injector` knows of. You haven't defined where should `java.lang.Boolean` came from - Guice cannot just pull the value out of nowhere and pass it there. You have to define `@Provides`, module, etc - it doesn't differ much from Java so read a Guice tutorial first injecting arguments in normal classes. Or verify that you really need to use Guice (is it a project requirement?) rather than just pass arguments by hand, since DI frameworks are not needed for DI.

Comment: Do you really want to let Guice create an instance of `ConfirmConfig` automatically? Sounds like you already have such an instance that you're able to build somehow and you only want to provide it to `GenerateReissueMaskOperation`, isn't it? In which case, just remove the `@Inject` on the case class.

Comment: It seems strange to inject attributes of config. Akka Play has some configuration features: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaConfig . For example, you might inject a special class `Configuration` and then read attributes from it. As well as special libraries as PureConfig (but it work better with TF/Cats approach).